# Django Appending Slashes to Static File URLs and getting 404 errors

Tags: python, django

I've tried all solutions that has been provided there but no luck.
I've added 'static' folder to the root.
This is an old django app that I've transferred to Godaddy's VPS with CentOS 6.
There is another non-python website on the server.

```
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName familyfn.com
ServerAlias www.familyfn.com

# Note: Whether or not django can write to a directory is controlled by filesys$

# Apache's internal directory auth has to give the vhost access to the wsgi.py $
<Directory /home/familysu/public_html/wsgi>
        Options None
        AllowOverride None
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>

# Apache's internal directory auth has to give the vhost access to directories $
<Directory /home/familysu/public_html/code/mediafiles>
        Options None
        AllowOverride None
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory /home/familysu/public_html/code/staticfiles>
        Options None
        AllowOverride None
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>
<Directory /home/familysu/public_html/code/breakdown/static>
        Options None
        AllowOverride None
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
</Directory>

# Use the following to restrict access during review. You'll need to generate t$
#<Location "/">
#   AuthName "familysu Review"
#   AuthType Basic
#   Require valid-user
#   AuthUserFile /home/familysu/public_html/reviewusers.htpasswd
#</Location>

# mod_wsgi works with the Alias directive such that aliased files and directori$
Alias /media/ /home/familysu/public_html/code/mediafiles/
Alias /static/  /home/familysu/public_html/code/staticfiles/
Alias /robots.txt /home/familysu/public_html/code/breakdown/static/robots.txt
Alias /favicon.ico /home/familysu/public_html/code/breakdown/static/favicon.ico

WSGIDaemonProcess www.familyfn.com  processes=2 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup www.familyfn.com
# Note: wsgi.py is in its own folder so the above directory permissions will ap$
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/familysu/public_html/wsgi/wsgi.py

LogLevel warn
ErrorLog /home/familysu/public_html/logs/error.log
CustomLog /home/familysu/public_html/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

setting.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(TOP_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(TOP_DIR, 'breakdown', 'static'),
]
```

django version 1.1.4; python version 2.6

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'staticfiles',
    'sky_redirects',

    'cms',
    'cms.plugins.text',
    'cms.plugins.picture',
    'cms.plugins.link',
    'cms.plugins.file',
    'cms.plugins.snippet',
    'cms.plugins.googlemap',
    'mptt',
    'publisher',

    'filebrowser',

    'mainsite.articles',
    'mainsite.zone_report',
    'mainsite.pressroom',
    'mainsite.downloads',

)
```

I've checked this:

```
python manage.py findstatic --verbosity 2 css/styles.css
```

and it found correct path:

```
Found 'css/styles.css' here:
  /home/familysu/public_html/code/breakdown/static/css/styles.css
```

It added slash at the end of each static file for some reason:
[image]

Comment: What if you visit http://.../static/css/styles.css? Does that result in 404? Does the file /home/familysu/public_html/code/staticfiles/css/styles.css exist?

Comment: Wait, Django 1.1; boy, is that old?

Comment: You *urgently* need to upgrade your Django version. It has been unsupported for years and is totally insecure.

Comment: if I visit http://.../static/css/styles.css then it added "/" to the end of link and shows 404 page http://.../static/css/styles.css/

Comment: I know it is old. But it is old website and we just transferred it to the new server and it should be live. We will update it one day

Answer (score 0):

I have a hard time remembering how static files used to work in 1.1. However, this line in your Apache configuration seems to be wrong:

```
Alias /static/  /home/familysu/public_html/code/staticfiles/code/breakdown/static/
```

Should probably be this:

```
Alias /static/ /home/familysu/public_html/
```

I think Django 1.1 didn't have `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` and `STATICFILES_DIRS`.